# search for occurences of an integer in a list in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, match

this is a really basic question, and I am probably not seeing something obvious but I am currently stuck with this problem:

In R, I generated a List of integers, made through the `sample()` function. Then want to find an exact pattern.

Should be obvious, but `grep` does the following:

1)

```
grep('03230', hugeListofNumbers)
>integer(0)
```

2)

```
pattern<-toString(03230)
x<-toString(hugeListofNumbers)

grep(pattern, x)
>[1] 1
```

3) And using `matchPattern` from the `Biostrings` Package:

```
matchPattern(pattern, x)

     start    end width
[1]   5146   5158    13 [0, 3, 2, 3, 2]
....
```

No result helps me find the occurences of the pattern. And although the last one using matchPattern seems ok, it finds some weird 13 characters long string that does not match in any way the 5 character long pattern...

What am I not seeing here? How can I just preform a normal grep search as in the shell??

Edit: 
To generate the list with the properties I needed I used:

```
hugeListofNumbers<-sample(c(0,1,2,3), 10^5, replace=TRUE, prob=NULL)
pattern<-sample(c(0,1,2,3), 5 , replace=TRUE, prob=NULL)
```

Comment: Can you add some code to generate a specific list of numbers for us to help you with? Something like HugeListOfNumbers <- c(1,2,23452435, 245) ?

Comment: I think it will never be the case that an R integer will ever have a leading `0` digit when coerced by a regex function to a character vector. Notice that your pattern value is `"3230"`, not `"03230"` My close vote is because I think this is isomorphic to a typographical error.

Comment: @BondedDust I am aware that the pattern value is different from the actual pattern. That is not a typographical error, but I am looking for the actual pattern regardless of its numeric significance. The same task could be performed with letters. The reason why I use integers, is for following steps where numeric operations are needed. That is why I tried converting it to string temporally for the search.

Comment: @waternova Edit has been made and the code is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution, which was, as expected, because I was overseeing a very basic problem: The `sample()` function of R returns a vector, so I could not match any pattern longer than 1, before converting it to a string.